# attributes of attributes of Enums?

Tags: python, enums

I'm not sure, if something like this is possible, but I would like to save more attributes to enum attributes (like value).

Example:

```
class Unit(Enum):
    mm = "millimeter"
```

`Unit.mm.value` would return "millimeter".

Now I would like to access a short version, it would be awesome, if I could implement something, that results in `Unit.mm.upper_case` returning "Millimeter".

I know I could create an extra function, that takes `Unit.mm` as an attribute, and returns the desired output, but I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Make the enum value a class that has a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an additional property on an `Enum` member like so:

```
from enum import Enum

class Unit(Enum):
    mm = 'millimeter'

    @property
    def capitalized(self):
        # self is the member here, e.g. Unit.mm
        return self.value.capitalize()

print(Unit.mm.capitalized)

>>>Millimeter
```

Here is the docs [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations).

Answer (score 2):

if you can derive the additional info purely from the name and value parts of your enum definition, you can use the property or method approach from Jacques above.

There's a second example in the [enum module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init) that describes how to override the `__new__` method to attach additional info to each enum member, without impacting the ability to use `Unit.mm.value` to fetch the definition.

```py
>>> class Coordinate(bytes, Enum):
...     """
...     Coordinate with binary codes that can be indexed by the int code.
...     """
...     def __new__(cls, value, label, unit):
...         obj = bytes.__new__(cls, [value])
...         obj._value_ = value
...         obj.label = label
...         obj.unit = unit
...         return obj
...     PX = (0, 'P.X', 'km')
...     PY = (1, 'P.Y', 'km')
...     VX = (2, 'V.X', 'km/s')
...     VY = (3, 'V.Y', 'km/s')
...

>>> print(Coordinate['PY'])
Coordinate.PY

>>> print(Coordinate(3))
Coordinate.VY

>>> print(Coordinate.VY.value)
3

>>> print(Coordinate.VY.unit)
km/s
```

Comment: That's great, I was looking for a way to do that!